# Why is this type error occuring?

Tags: haskell, fold

```
solveRPN :: String -> Double
solveRPN rpnString = head foldl . foldingFunction [] . words
    where foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys
          foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys
          foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "-" = (x - y):ys
          foldingFunction xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

The above code produces the error below. I've tried changing `String` to `[Char]` and replacing double quotes for single quotes but I keep getting this error:

> ```
> _01.hs:874:50: error:
>     • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
>       Expected type: String
>         Actual type: Char
>     • In the first argument of ‘read’, namely ‘numberString’
>       In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘read numberString’
>       In the expression: read numberString : xs
>     | 874 |           foldingFunction xs numberString = read numberString:xs
>     |                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Failed, 1 module loaded.
> ```

Comment: When you read the error message, what did it mean to you? What parts make sense? What parts don't? It's very difficult to help with beginner errors without knowing specifically what isn't making sense to you.

Comment: What does this have to do with LYAH? Also, this isn't "thrown" - it's not an exception, it's a compilation error.

Comment: Type signatures not only help readability, but they also help localize errors.  In this case, you could add a type signature to `foldingFunction` and the error message would perhaps be more understandable to you.  If you can not write the type of `foldingFunction` then that is a great exercise to start with.

Comment: To all of you: the answers made sense. I will take the advise with me in learning Haskell, and sorry to burden you with so many beginners questions.

Answer (score 4):

The original solution in Learn you a Haskell book looks like this

```
solveRPN :: (Num a, Read a) => String -> a  
solveRPN = head . foldl foldingFunction [] . words  
    where   foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys  
            foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys  
            foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "-" = (y - x):ys  
            foldingFunction xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

When I compare it with your snippet, there are two things that cause the error:

1) You misplaced the composition operator in composition chain. Instead of this

```
head foldl . foldingFunction [] . words
```

you need this

```
head . foldl foldingFunction [] . words
```

You can read it as taking `head` after folding with `foldingFunction` after calling `words`, where each "after" is composition operator.

2) You used a composition but you still left argument `rpnString`. If you want to use a composition you have to omit the argument that comes to the chain. So you can either omit the argument:

```
solveRPN :: String -> Double
solveRPN = head . foldl foldingFunction [] . words
    where   foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys
            foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys
            foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "-" = (y - x):ys
            foldingFunction xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

or you can omit the composition chain:

```
solveRPN :: String -> Double
solveRPN rpnString = head (foldl foldingFunction [] (words rpnString))
    where   foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys
            foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys
            foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "-" = (y - x):ys
            foldingFunction xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

Comment: Thanks Erik and Willem. Very constructive and understandable!

Answer (score 2):

The error is actually located in the *outer* expression:

```
solveRPN rpnString = head foldl . foldingFunction [] . words
```

You here call `head` on `foldl`, so that means that we expect that `foldl` has a certain type `[a -> b]`, since `head` can then obtain the first element of that list, and that element is that used for further processing. But [**`foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) of course is not a list.

Another problem is that this clause has an explicit parameter `rpnString` that you ignore: it looks like you did an *eta*-reduction, but only removed the parameter in the body of the function, and not in the head.

If we resolve the two errors, we have a working parser:

```
solveRPN :: String -> Double
solveRPN = head . foldl foldingFunction [] . words

foldingFunction :: [Double] -> String -> [Double]
foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys
foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys
foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "-" = (x - y):ys
foldingFunction xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

But there is a **semantical error**: note that `x` is the top of the stack (the latest number you have added) whereas `y` is the subtop of the stack. As a result if you perform a subtraction, you need to push `y - x` on the stack:

```
solveRPN :: String -> Double
solveRPN = head . foldl foldingFunction [] . words

foldingFunction :: [Double] -> String -> [Double]
foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "*" = (x * y):ys
foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "+" = (x + y):ys
foldingFunction (x:y:ys) "-" = (y - x):ys
foldingFunction xs numberString = read numberString:xs
```

Since the other operators are *commutative*, it does not matter in which order you use the operators. We now obtain correct results. For example:

```
Prelude> solveRPN "14 25 * 13 - 2 *"
674.0
```

Some tips for improvement:

1. use a `where` clause, such that you only define `foldingFunction` locally.
2. generalize the output type to any `Num` type, in that case we can reuse the parser for all kinds of numbers (`Int`s, `Float`s, etc.).
3. You can encapsulate the logic that maps the string `"*"` to the multiplication and thus reduce the complexity of the code.